# How to create debug log in Amazon S3 bucket while running a code in Amazon Sagemaker

Tags: debugging, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am having a very big loop. I wanted to run it over the Amazon Sage maker. For this I need to create debug log in Amazon S3 bucket. How to do it?

Comment: Why not use the Cloudwatch log streams for this? - You can directly search / query / analyze your logs here. Publishing logs into S3 is a suboptimal way. You can use `awsme` for publishing if you are using python.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using sagemaker with you own container (or with a pre-built one). If you are using tensorflow then you can set the `model_dir` variable to a S3 bucket, since S3 filesystem is supported by tensorflow. Then you can use tensorboard pointing to that bucket, like this:

```
AWS_REGION=<your-region> AWS_LOG_LEVEL=3 tensorboard --logdir s3://sagemaker-customname/result/
```

You need the appropriate permissions in your container to write in the S3 bucket. If you want an example of how this could work, I made a repository [here](https://github.com/roccopietrini/TFSagemakerDetection)